# Materials in GoCD

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, go-cd

We have two agents - one agents is in company's internal network and another agent is in amazon. Git is our material. We use private ip to access the repo from the machine in the network and public ip is used to access the repo from amazon machine.

Our pipeline has two stages - first stage use machine in internal network and second stage uses amazon instance.

There is a constraint in the local network that we cant use the public IP to access the git repo.

Is there a way, we can configure material at stage level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your stages does, and also your question is not very clear.

But I would recommend to separate it into two pipelines, so you can assign different agents to each pipeline at the GoCD environment level. Otherwise you'll not be able to route the stages to a specific agent.

Pipelines can run sequentially if you properly configure the materials, so your configuration should be at the Pipeline level, and not at the stage level.

This also gives you the ability to use Pipeline Templates.

Comment: Put +1 but I think your answer somewhat hints stages (in a given pipeline) are not sequential while that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by having host file entry in the agents. Basically, we can use the same url for the material and we can have entry in /etc/hosts which resolves to the corresponding ip.